# JMenuBar broken when running .jar file on linux (i.MX processor)

Tags: java, swing, arm, embedded-linux, jmenubar

I'm trying to run a swing application on a custom (yocto) linux distribution running on an i.MX processor (32bit ARM).

I've moved my jre to the embedded OS's filesystem, and I'm successfully running my application using `./jre/bin/java -jar App.jar`. Everything is functioning correctly, except for the menu bar. I can click to open a submenu, but as soon as I click again or move my mouse it will close. (As an aside, I have mnemonics set for my menu options. These still work perfectly.)

I'm using the standard create `JMenuItem`, add to `JMenu`, add to `JMenuBar` design pattern, developing in windows on NetBeans, and creating my .jar file with Ant. I've tried multiple JREs, currently working with `jdk-8u201-linux-arm32-vfp-hflt`.

Any advice regarding where to start troubleshooting is appreciated.

Comment: Do you get any errors via terminal? Did you try to run it on another OS?

Comment: No errors from terminal. The application is running nicely - I just can't use the MenuBar.

I have it running on Windows 10 with no issues. Apparently there are no issues on Ubuntu 16.04 but I haven't tested this personally.

Comment: Are you lost between `JMenuBar` and `Menubar` ?

Comment: I don't think so - I'm using the JMenuBar class defined in the swing libraries to create a menu bar for my application. 

I'm working on a simplified example. I was hoping that there were known issues between the ARM jre and x11/xwayland - no such luck.